# RequiredObjectIsNullException while rebuilding the reporting database - RebuildTaskDataProvider

Tags: xdb, reporting

I have setup secondary analytics db and trying to rebuild reporting database by going to `"sitecore/admin/RebuildReportingDB.aspx"`. However when I open `"RebuildReportingDB.aspx"` I am getting below error.

Using Sitecore8.1 update3

> [RequiredObjectIsNullException: RebuildTaskDataProvider]
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.History.ReportingStorageManager.GetRebuildStatus()
>   +98    ASP.sitecore_admin_rebuildreportingdb_aspx.OnPreLoad(EventArgs e) +77    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2982

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending sometime I have noticed that I made a mistake(tags were not closed properly) while updating "TimeToClearStorage" setting in Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.config which broke the config so "RebuildReportingDB.aspx" was throwing above error.

For rebuilding reporting database Sitecore recommends to create a fresh analytic DB (reporting.secondary) and copy few tables from existing analytic DB to fresh DB during the rebuilding process. Also recommends to increase "TimeToClearStorage" to  ensure that you allow more time for the clear storage process while these tables are being copied. Find more information here https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database

So while updating the setting I added

```
TimeToClearStorage>0.00:01:00</TimeToClearStorage
instead of
<TimeToClearStorage>0.00:01:00</TimeToClearStorage>
Notice missing '<' and '>' for tag.
```

Comment: Could you share the code with us, please, both before and after and highlighting both the problem and the solution? I would like to upvote this, as it may help others in the future, but as it stands there isn't enough information provided for me to up-vote your question or the solution.